# $_POST value returns empty array

Tags: php, apache, server-configuration

I have an Apache server and there is a problem sending post request to the server. While I send a post to the server it returns an empty array. My server is ubuntu 14.04 and php installed packages are:

```php
    libapache2-mod-php5 
    php-net-ftp
    php5
    php5-cli
    php5-common
    php5-json
    php5-mcrypt
    php5-mysql
    php5-readline
```

By the way, I have recently tried to install postfix and mailutils on the server but it was failed. I guess there might be something wrong with the configuration.

Comment: How did you test if `$_POST` is empty ?

Comment: How do you know it's empty? Could be a problem with your code too, not necessary with the server.

Comment: do `print_r($_POST)` in your code, for better help provide code

Comment: Please add the form code as well...

Comment: Are you explicitly using post method either with html form `method='post'`  or similarly with curl or javascript? or... 
are you redirecting somewhere else in your post 'landing' php? (e.g. `header("Location: ...)`?

Comment: I have created an index.php file and just wrote var_dump($_POST) into it and tried with postman to check

Comment: paste your code , may be the problem is with your code

Comment: Did you try `var_dump($_REQUEST);` ?

Comment: Certain PHP frameworks reset the variable for to prevent raw/unsafely access. Are you using any PHP framework? If not the best option for to debug is read stdin

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was working on my dev machine but not production. The problem appeared when the POST was processed by another page. I had used ob_start on one of my shared scripts and when I removed it the problem disappeared. I tried to recreate the problem by placing ob_start where it was but the problem was not there anymore. It is worth a try.